# How to open a uri in file manager in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a button in my app when user click on it, it'll open a specific URI in file manager but the best I could've done is that the button opens recent tab in default file manager.

Please, if it's possible, suggest me a code which opens a chooser for user to choose between his file manager applications and when user chose, that file manager opens in specific URI that I defined in my code.

Here is my code:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
val uri = Uri.parse(
    //my path
)
intent.data = uri
intent.type = "*/*"
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"))
```

Also one of the users suggested me to use INITIAL_URI I've did it like this but didn't work :

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            val uri = Uri.parse(
                //my path
            )
            intent.data = uri
            intent.type = "*/*"
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri)
            intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true)
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"))
```

Comment: Have a look at INITIAL_URI.

Comment: what do you get instead of the expected result?

Comment: @blackapps I've just lokked at INITIAL_URI from another questions but yet default file manager opens in recent tab.

Comment: @xklakoux As I said default file manager opens at "recent" tab.

Comment: Post your code in your post and tell which Android version in use. Further: google as what you want has been asked here many times.

Comment: @blackapps yes already tried all those answers didn't get answer from them so I asked, and I've already posted my code which were needed. I've tried my app on almost every android devices from API 23 to API 29.

Comment: @blackapps There you go m8

Comment: You cannot use a file path for initial uri.

Comment: @blackapps it's folder path and please if you know the answer simply post a piece of code to help me.

Comment: If one cannot use a file path or a folder path for an initial uri then a good question would be: "Then what kind of uri is usable?".

Comment: @Mr.Sha1  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553040/9846650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> suggest me a code which opens a chooser for user to choose between his file manager applications and when user chose, that file manager opens in specific URI that I defined in my code

That has never been a pattern in Android app development. There is no standard `Intent` action for what you seek that is likely to be implemented by much of anything, let alone a significant number of file manager apps.

Comment: Thanks dear friend for understanding and trying to help me. What about opening default file manager in a specific URI ?

Comment: @ShayanDamghanpour: There has never been any official support for that either, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help wish you a bugless code :) <3

Answer (score 0):

```
fun openNewTabWindow(urls: String, context : Context) {
    val uris = Uri.parse(urls)
    val intents = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uris)
    val myV = Bundle()
    myV.putBoolean("new_window", true)
    intents.putExtras(myV)
    context.startActivity(intents)
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot for your help. First of all I needed to set type of the intent or I got exception when tried to call the function so I added `.apply` after `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uris)`and then set the type to `*/*` but still when the function get called the file manager start at recent tab not at the URI we defined. Any idea for that problem?